# Randomize and animate multiple Start and End Angles of Arc

Tags: animation, d3.js, tween

I'm trying to create a visual that is a modification of the [Arc Tween](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5100636) demo. In it, I want an array of data to define the colors and general radius of each arc, and on an interval, both the start and end angles should slowly animate. But I think the way I'm defining each arc is causing things to over animate.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <title>Arcs</title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

SCRIPT

```
// Modified from Arc Tween
// https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5100636

var tau = 2 * Math.PI; // http://tauday.com/tau-manifesto
var overlap = 50

var jsonArcs = [
  { "base_radius": 370, "color" : "red"},
  { "base_radius": 330, "color" : "orange"},
  { "base_radius": 290, "color" : "yellow"},
  { "base_radius": 250, "color" : "green"},
  { "base_radius": 210, "color" : "blue" },
  { "base_radius": 170, "color" : "purple"},
  { "base_radius": 130, "color" : "black"},
  { "base_radius": 90, "color" : "red"}
];


var arc = d3.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.random() * tau; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.random() * tau; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return d.base_radius - overlap * Math.random(); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return d.base_radius + overlap * Math.random(); });

var center_def = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(0)
    .outerRadius(60)
    .startAngle(0);


var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

  var path = g.selectAll("path")
      .data(jsonArcs) 
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return d.color; })
      .attr("d", arc);


var center = g.append("path")
    .datum({endAngle: tau})
    .style("fill", "black")
    .attr("d", center_def);


d3.interval(function() {

  path.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween(Math.random() * tau, arc));
}, 2500);

function arcTween(newAngle, obj) {

  return function(d) {

    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);

    return function(t) {

      d.endAngle = interpolate(t);

      return obj(d);
    };
  };
}
```

Instead of each arc smoothly animating from start angles to new angles, the entire visual jumps multiple times to a new state.

How do I configure this function such that each arc smoothly transitions its start and end angles from old to new?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792685/i-can-tween-a-d3-arcs-endangle-but-not-its-startangle-what-am-i-doing-wrong But I don't know how to invoke multiple arcs using the data provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here

1. Your arc function is going to return random radii every call, which is not what I think you want.  You could transition an arc from one inner/outer radius to the next, but for simplicity, let's say that each path only initially gets a random radius
2. In order to transition from one the old pair of start/end angles to the new one you'll need to store the current angles somewhere.  We'll store it in a [local variable](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/e1192fe405703d8321a5187350910e08), which will be tied to each path
3. Because each path will have a different inner/outer radius, we'll need to have a different arc function for each segment as well.

working code here:

```
    var tau = 2 * Math.PI; // http://tauday.com/tau-manifesto
    var overlap = 50;
    var currentSegment = d3.local();
    var segmentRadius = d3.local();

    var jsonArcs = [
      { "base_radius": 370, "color" : "red"},
      { "base_radius": 330, "color" : "orange"},
      { "base_radius": 290, "color" : "yellow"},
      { "base_radius": 250, "color" : "green"},
      { "base_radius": 210, "color" : "blue" },
      { "base_radius": 170, "color" : "purple"},
      { "base_radius": 130, "color" : "black"},
      { "base_radius": 90, "color" : "red"}
    ];

    var arc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(function() { return segmentRadius.get(this).innerRadius })
        .outerRadius(function() { return segmentRadius.get(this).outerRadius });

    var center_def = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(0)
        .outerRadius(60)
        .startAngle(0);

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +svg.attr("width"),
        height = +svg.attr("height"),
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var path = g.selectAll("path")
        .data(jsonArcs)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return d.color; })
        .each(function(d) {
          var angles = randomAngles();
          d.startAngle = angles.startAngle;
          d.endAngle = angles.endAngle;
          segmentRadius.set(this, {
            innerRadius: d.base_radius - overlap * Math.random(),
            outerRadius: d.base_radius + overlap * Math.random()
          });
        })
        .attr("d", arc)
        .each(function(d) {currentSegment.set(this, d)});

    var center = g.append("path")
        .datum({endAngle: tau})
        .style("fill", "black")
        .attr("d", center_def);

    d3.interval(function() {
      path.transition()
          .duration(750)
          .attrTween("d", arcTween);
    }, 2500);

    function arcTween() {
      var thisPath = this;
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(currentSegment.get(this), randomAngles());
      currentSegment.set(this, interpolate(0));

      return function(t) {
        return arc.call(thisPath, interpolate(t));
      };
    }
    function randomAngles() {
      var angles = [Math.random() * tau, Math.random() * tau].sort();
      return {startAngle: angles[0], endAngle: angles[1]};
    }
```

Notice a few things about the changed code:

1. I set the random initial angles in an each call on the path just before the "d" attribute is set
2. I stored the segment radii in the segmentRadius d3.local variable at the end of that same chain and also after each interpolation is set in the call to the transition
3. In the transition function I needed to call arc to preserve the 'this' of the path so that 'this' would be correct in arc.innerRadius when retrieving the segmentRadius.
4. d3.interpolate can happily handle objects and not just numbers.

I have a similar example that I've been working on [here](https://bl.ocks.org/ryanlsimms/6092ddf8bce46189bb328c5b88e09739) if you'd like to learn more.

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense. I was struggling with the randomization of the radii every call, but I didn't think of storing the previous state. I also wasn't familiar enough with "each"